# tailwind grid issue React (responsive col-span showing in HTML but not working as expected)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, css-grid

I have a grid that *should* be doing what I want. This is a jsfiddle of the behavior I'm expected. It depends on this responsive code: `col-span-3 md:col-span-2` for instance for one of the items.

Here is the issue:
I check the HTML of the page, and my dynamic breakpoint col-spans *are* showing. So it should be doing what I expect. However, they are not assuming the md: col-span when the viewport expands. What could be the issue?

Here is the wrapper for my component:

```
<div className="max-w-5xl">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-6 gap-10 p-6">
          {
            supportedArray.map((card, idx) => <SupportCard key={idx} {...card} />
          )}
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my component:

```
import { ISupportCard } from "~/types"

const SupportCard = (card: ISupportCard) => {
  return (
    <div className={`bg-white card shadow-xl aspect-[portrait] overflow-hidden rounded-t-xl rounded-b-3xl col-span-${card.mobileSpan} md:col-span-${card.colSpan} ${card.customClasses ?? ""}`}>
      <div className="relative">
        <img className={`w-full h-full object-cover ${card.imgClasses ?? ""}`} src={card.image} alt={card.alt_text ?? card.title} />
        <h3 className="absolute text-neutralBlack bottom-0 flex justify-center items-center text-lg md:text-2xl font-bold bg-[rgba(255,255,255,0.5)] w-full card-title p-3 backdrop-blur">{card.title}</h3>
      </div>
      <div className="relative card-body hidden md:flex flex-1">
        <p className="text-xl font-medium">{card.copy}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SupportCard
```

Here is the shape of the data coming in:

```
export interface ISupportCard {
  imgClasses?: string
  colSpan: number
  mobileSpan: number
  customClasses?: string
  title: string
  image: string
  alt_text?: string
  copy: string
}
```

Here is one of the objects:

```
{
    colSpan: 6,
    mobileSpan: 3,
    imgClasses: "aspect-square md:aspect-auto object-[40%] md:object-fill",
    title: "Organizations",
    image: "/images/cards/support-organizations.jpg",
    alt_text: "Organizations",
    copy: `Copy...`
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have a dictionary for `col-span-*` to Tailwind class names:

  ```
  const SupportCard = (card: ISupportCard) => {
    const COL_SPANS = {
      1: 'col-span-1',
      2: 'col-span-2',
      // …
    };
    const MD_COL_SPANS = {
      1: 'md:col-span-1',
      2: 'md:col-span-2',
      // …
    };
    // …
    return (
      <div className={`… ${COL_SPANS[card.mobileSpan]} ${MD_COL_SPANS [card.colSpan]} …`}>
  ```
- Use the `style` attribute for truly dynamic properties:

  ```
  const SupportCard = (card: ISupportCard) => {
    return (
      <div
        className={`… md:col-span-[--md-col-span] …`}
        style={{
          gridColumns: `span ${card.mobileSpan} / span ${card.mobileSpan}`,
          '--md-col-span': `span ${card.colSpan} / span ${card.colSpan}`,
        }}
      >
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known spans:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^col-span-[1-6]$/ },
      {
        pattern: /^col-span-[2-4]$/,
        variants: ['md'],
      },
      // …
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```

Comment: Can I set the class name as a string literal before the return statement? Would that count as an unbroken string?

Comment: As long as you do not use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names.

Comment: Can't I use an arbitrary value?

Comment: You can! As long as you do not use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like we have to declare the class_names first, before the component being rendered and Tailwind will keep these classes when purge and render to the website.
By this way, we can still using the concat string or literal template.

```
let classNames = `grid gap-3 grid-cols-8 grid-cols-7 grid-cols-6 grid-cols-5 grid-cols-4 grid-cols-3 grid-cols-2`;

for(int i = 1; i<=8; i++)
    classNames = `grid gap-3 grid-cols-${i}`;

return(
    <div className={className}>
    // something
    </div>
);
```